# What iOS browsers support Firefox Sync?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, web-browser

My Mom wants to be able to use Firefox Sync to sync her bookmarks between her laptop and her iPad. What browsers support Firefox Sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best browser for this is [Mercury Browser](http://www.ilegendsoft.com/software/mercurybrowser/) ([app store link](http://itunes.apple.com/app/mercury-web-browser-pro-most/id348701575?mt=8)). It supports full Firefox browser syncing. There is a .99 upgrade to remove ads.
[image: Mercury Browser]

Comment: I think this app has been taken off the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Firefox Home](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-home/id380366933?mt=8) (if it is available in your country)? It's not a browser but you can sync your bookmark, and open them via Safari.

Comment: Though not a browser, Firefox Home is definately a great tool.

Comment: Firefox Home is good, but I'm looking for a full fledged web browser. Thanks though!

Comment: I think this app has been taken off the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of [iLunascape (FREE)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ilunascape/id380065805) and [360 Web ($0.99)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/360-web-browser-download-manager/id387737097) to support Firefox Sync.

Answer (score 0):

Now Mercury Browser not support Firefox Sync. Foxbrowser is a good alternative. [ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foxbrowser/id550365886?mt=8 ]

Comment: I think this app has also been taken off the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-web-browser/id989804926?mt=8) is now available for iPad.

[image]